# How do I name the adjoint of an operation in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

For example, if I've defined the operation `PlusEqual`, I'd like to say

```
operation MinusEqual = Adjoint PlusEqual;
```

but this produces a syntax error.

Is the only way to do this by exhaustively re-listing all arguments and functors?

```
operation MinusEqual (all_args_and_types_again) : ReturnType {
    body (...) {
        return Adjoint AddEqual(all_args);
    }
    adjoint auto;
    controlled auto;
    controlled adjoint auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an immutable symbol for `MinusEqual` inside the body of an operation which will use it (you can't define it globally):

```
operation UseMinusEqual () : Unit {
    ...
    let MinusEqual = Adjoint PlusEqual;
    MinusEqual(...);
}
```

If you need `MinusEqual` to be a globally visible operation, there is no shorthand syntax for this right now, so the only way to do it is a full operation definition like you say.